# Stair Railing came apart

Tags: wood, stairs, adhesive, railing

[image]Hey everyone,
I appreciate any help with this.
My stair railing seemed to come apart towards the top where it curves before connecting to the wall.
This confused me because I don’t see anyway to connect these two pieces. I have tried glueing but didn’t seem to work.
Any idea on how to repair this?enter image description here

Comment: What type of material is it made out of?  Any small plugs/buttons on the outside angle that might hide screw/s?

Comment: Can you give us some bigger pics, and include one from below?

Answer (score 2):

The pic is hard to decern details from.

I would try to drill some small 1/16" pilot holes from the left side to allow a couple of [Trim Screws](https://www.architecturaldepot.com/772691-17732-2.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=20205203912&utm_content=&utm_term=&gclid=Cj0KCQjw756lBhDMARIsAEI0AglPYO9wFfQUGCq1z28s9r6PB8Q4hzJSb_wctPrr9C3ObMSRZW02t2MaAm8oEALw_wcB&ppcsclkid=Cj0KCQjw756lBhDMARIsAEI0AglPYO9wFfQUGCq1z28s9r6PB8Q4hzJSb_wctPrr9C3ObMSRZW02t2MaAm8oEALw_wcB&ppcstrkid=1115274693&ppcsu=xhg7f5djqtopedhcra)  to be installed that would intersect the flat face of the right side piece.

Clamp the 2 pieces together with a little wood glue and screw in the screws. 2 1/2 to 3 1/2 should work.
The exact length you need you will have to determine.  I cannot tell by the pic.

The trim screws counter sink themselves nicely.  Then fill the holes with a little putty and paint to match.

Comment: Thank you so much this help me repair the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use wood glue with a clamp to hold it in place for at least 24 hours. To make sure it held I would also use a nail gun on the underside of either piece angled diagonally to help hold it together.

Comment: Wood glue helped! Thank you!